# Check whether a Movieclip exists in library

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I am trying to add sound from library. Like
`backGroundSound:Sound = new BackGroundSound();`  // BackGroundSound is mp3 file class name.

I want to use this as common for all developers who use Backgroundsound for their game.

I want to check before adding it like whether it is exported in library to prevent compilation error.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: These checks should be performed at compile time, after all, the definition of `BackgroundSound` class should be available. So, after you compile this, `BackgroundSound` will be available. But, to prevent a compilation error, you have to manually check the prerequisites.

Comment: thanks, but i was wondering if there is some code to check whether a sound file or movieclip do exists in library? Any how Im using try catch to avoid comipler error problem.

Comment: You want to check if a class is available at runtime, right? That answer below from fsbmain gives seemingly correct code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var classExist:Boolean = isClassExists("BackGroundSound");

private function isClassExists(className:String, domain:ApplicationDomain = null):Boolean
{
    var res:Boolean;

    if(domain)
    {
        res = domain.hasDefinition(className);
    }
    else
    {
        res = getDefinitionByName(className);
        //or the same
        //res = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.hasDefinition(className);
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: Thanks fsbmain, seems to do the job... :)